# Rails store session on filesystem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I've run into a cookie store overflow problem on rails using devise, and it looks like it might be time to use a different session store. Ofcourse redis would solve the problem, but I don't want to use redis on development machines. I wonder if there is a filesystem store like php. I just want to use this to store Sessions on a development machine. I have searched google, but haven't found anything concrete. This shouldn't be too complicated, I am sure I am missing something obvious

Comment: Why can't you use redis ? It is the right solution for your requirements. Having said that, are you actually looking for a method to open a file locally, write to it and then read it afterwards inside your rails app?

Comment: no I am looking for a session store that uses files like php. I don't want to install redis on my development machine, that's all. Also since I use a 2 laptops and alternate between windows and linux quite often, I really don't want to setup redis on all of them. A filesystem suits my development needs. I will use a redis store for production (or testing)

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee I don't know how complicated it is on Windows, but on Linux setting up redis is not more than `sudo apt-get install redis` (or `sudo yum install redis`). You run it simply by executing `redis-server` (no config required if you don't want to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Rails has a decoupled way of managing session, you can implement a custom session store that uses files for storing it's data.
However, keep in mind that this must be strictly used for development, file I/O speeds are nowhere as fast as RAM and can become a serious bottleneck to your application.

Here a complete implementation of a custom session store using the filesystem ( the code is not mine, the link is at the end )

```
class CustomFileStore < ActionDispatch::Session::AbstractStore
  def get_session(env, session_id)
    session_data = {}
    session_id ||= generate_sid
    File.open(tmp_file(session_id),'r') do |f|
      data = f.read
      session_data = ::Marshal.load(data) unless data.empty?
    end rescue nil
    [session_id, session_data]
  end

  def set_session(env, session_id, session_data, options)
    File.open(tmp_file(session_id), 'w+') do |f|
      encoded = ::Marshal.dump(session_data)
      f.write(encoded)
    end
    session_id
  end

  def destroy_session(env, session_id, options)
    File.unlink(tmp_file(session_id)) if File.exists?(tmp_file(session_id))
    generate_sid
  end

  def tmp_file(session_id)
    File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'sessions', session_id)
  end
end
```

Save it as "custom_file_store.rb" in the "lib" folder, and then configure your app to use it using the following code in "config/initializers/session_store.rb"
( change RailsApp with your application's name )

```
RailsApp::Application.config.session_store :custom_file_store
```

That's all !
Check out the article from the original author of this code here :
http://bradpauly.com/blog/2013-02-01-rails-3-custom-session-store.html